# error en variable laravel 5.8 para crear listado

Tags: laravel

**EmpleadosController**

```
public function index()
{
    //

    $tickets = Empleados::all();
    return view('empleados.tickets', compact('tickets'));
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/search','EmpleadosController@search');
Route::get('/tickets', 'EmpleadosController@index');
```

**tickets.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <div class="container col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h2> Tickets </h2>
            </div>

                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Nombre</th>
                            <th>Rut</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    @foreach($empleados as $empleado)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{!! $empleado->Nombre !!} </td>
                                <td>{!! $empleado->Rut !!}</td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>

        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

Y dá el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dice que mi variable no existe.

Answer (score 2):

El error es exactamente eso, en el controlador creas una variable llamada tickets:

```
$tickets = Empleados::all();
return view('empleados.tickets', compact('tickets'));
```

Que luego pasas en la vista creando un array con la función compact. Entonces hasta ahora solo tienes una variable llamada tickets.

En el html o la vista indicas con un for (usando blade) que se creará un tr por cada elemento del arreglo empleados:

```
@foreach($empleados as $empleado)
```

Y ese arreglo no existe, debes o cambiar el nombre de la variable tickets a empleados o cambiar el for por tickets:

```
@foreach($tickets as $empleado)
```

Comment: muchas gracias me funciono esa era la solucion